# Can't find where to change meta description, keywords and title

Tags: magento-1.7, php, seo

I've checked in both the admin area configuration > design > HTML Head.

The current title, description and keywords currently don't come from here although in the backend file head.phtml the code written pulls in these Fields I believe.

(I'm still learning Magento)

Here is the code in the previous mentioned file

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2011 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php echo $this->getContentType() ?>" />
<title><?php echo $this->getTitle() ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getKeywords()) ?>" />
<meta name="robots" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getRobots()) ?>" />
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo $this->getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,800,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/jquery-1.7.min.js') ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/scripts.js') ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js') ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/jquery.color.js') ?>"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var BLANK_URL = '<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getJsUrl('blank.html') ?>';
    var BLANK_IMG = '<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getJsUrl('spacer.gif') ?>';
//]]>
</script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
 <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today." /></a>
</div>
<![endif]--> 
<!--[if IE]>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<![endif]-->
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getTranslatorScript() ?>
<?php echo $this->getIncludes() ?>
```

I tried commenting out line 29
`<meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />`
This makes the meta description vanish so I know this is the correct file generating the text but I can't figure out where I edit the input fields?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If There is a CMS page then go to the **CMS >> Page >> Add/ edit you find the *META*** tab in that you can add **Keywords** and **Description**. and title will come form **Page Information >> Page Title**.

If you load the product then This will load from the **Catalog >> Manage Products >> you find in *Meta Information*** Tab in that.

Magento Load this data Dynamically.

Hope you got the Proper Answers.

Comment: Thankyou - this was the exact solution @Keyul Shah

Comment: @dannyw24 You welcome :)

Answer (score 11):

The meta data is different from page to page.
For example, in the product page the meta data comes from the `Meta title`, `Meta description` and `Meta keywords` attributes of the products you are viewing. The same goes for categories and CMS pages.
These values can be set from the layout file for any page like this:

```
<page_handle_here>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title"><title>Meta title here</title></action>
        <action method="setDescription" translate="description"><description>Meta description here</description></action>
        <action method="setKeywords" translate="keywords"><keywords>Meta keywords here</keywords></action>
    </reference>
</page_handle_here>
```

or from the controller action specific for the page you are viewing like this after calling `$this->loadLayout()`:

```
$head = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
if ($head){
    $head->setTitle($this->__('Meta title here'));
    $head->setDescription($this->__('Meta description here'));
    $head->setKeywords($this->__('Meta keywords here'));
}
```

If the above cases do not apply for your page then the default values will be used. The default values can be found in `System->Configuration->Design->HTMl Head`. They are called `Default Title`, `Default Description`, `Default Keywords`.
These default values can be different on different store views.

Comment: This is a brilliant Answer however, the other answer actually led me to the solution can't believe I over looked this.

Comment: @marius ... How do we check in xml layout  that methods are available or exists like method="setTitle" , method="setDescription", method="setKeywords" and other methods in layout files..and what is the translate means and what is the use of it. .. thanks

Comment: @MagentoBoy you should be able to call those methods in any layout handle inside '<reference name="head">...'. The "head" block supports those methods. And `translate="title"` means that the text inside the tag `<title>` will be translated before it is used.

Comment: @Marius ...means all this methods are from block files?? like method use for head, root, content handle?? methods called from their block files for with they belongs to?

Comment: @MagentoBoy Yes. And be careful. you can even call methods that don't exist through the magic of `__call`. So anything that starts with `set`, `get`, `uns`, `has` can be used even if the method does not actually exist.

Comment: @Marius ..sorry, I might be asking one more silly question?? why it is required for translation and what is the translation means??

Comment: @Marius ... Thanks, I have checked head.php file in block and yes it is existed and means I can call any methods which it binlongs too... Thanks I have got new things from you.

Comment: @Marius how can I check all my categories have meta tags