# How to implement per page meta description and keywords in Magento?

Tags: seo, meta-tags

I'm trying to change meta description and keywords (I know keywords aren't useful) in Magento CMS pages, but the site is still outputting the sitewide default values. What am I missing?

Comment: make sure you are not using any extension, if so, then configure it properly. Otherwise, if you set the meta in CMS page it should show up

Answer (score 1):

If There is a CMS page then go to the **CMS >> Page >> Add/ edit** you find the META tab in that you can add Keywords and Description. and title will come form **Page Information >> Page Title.**

If you load the product then This will load from the Catalog >> Manage Products >> you find in Meta Information Tab in that.

Found at
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/13306

Comment: How can i bulk update seo keywords for categories, which means i need to bulk update category page title, meta description, keywords, Does this possible.